# Navigating to different user controls in silverlight without creating a new instance of the user controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, singleton

Currently I am able to navigate between multiple user controls in silverlight. However everytime i navigate to a new user control, all the code in that user control is run again. Normally this wouldn't be a problem but, in my scenario one of the user controls takes around 50 seconds to load because of a monster query it is running via WCF service.

So how can i navigate to different user controls without creating a new instance of those user controls?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to research some [creational software design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern).

I would recommend either an [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) or a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but the pattern you choose is going to depend on your requirements and you may find another one suits you better.

I would highly recommend you purchase [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612). It is a fantastic, ground-breaking work which no serious C# programmer should be without.

Comment: I agree about the book. I was already thinking of using the singleton pattern (hence the singleton tag) but i have no clue how to make a usercontrol in silverlight to be singleton. But i think what i might try is to have a regular c# class that follows the singleton pattern and that class will contain all the user controls that i need. I have no idea if it will work but i'm gonna try that for now.

Comment: @rage - Perhaps you should consider passing the data to the control, rather than having the control fetch the data? You can use [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) if you need to implement control features within your main code.

Comment: that's also a good idea and i will try it when i am officially on the clock. I was able to achieve the functionality i wanted by creating a singleton class that has the usercontrols that i want to navigate between. I really do need that book though.